# Java to Excel - dynamic updates

Tags: java, excel, rtd

I need to display some dynamic data - an array of constantly updating values - from a java server onto an excel sheet. I have been looking at xlloop but this seems to be more a request/reply infrastructure - i.e. have to press F9 to poll for the latest values - is it possible to "push" the values from the java server onto the cells in the sheet via something like RTD each time the values change in the server ?

Comment: So you want to refresh an excel sheet?

Comment: this might be helpfull. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648762/writing-multiple-csv-files-from-excel-using-java-and-jexcelapi

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file (which can be opened by Microsoft Excel) stores tabular data  in plain-text form. So, you can push data using java application to CSV files easily.

For more information, go to 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values